# Retrieves and display endless amount of numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

I"m trying to make a program that retrieves an endless amount of numbers that user inputs until the user quits and display the numbers .Here is the code I have so far.After entering the first and second number it shows an exception at the line array1[i]=s1

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Program_2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=1,i;
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] array1= new String[a];     
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {   


        System.out.println("Enter Value Number "+ (i+1));
        System.out.println("Press Q or q to Exit");
        String s1=sn.next();
        if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
        {               
            for(i=0;i<a;i++)
            {                   
                System.out.println("Value of Number "+(i+1)+" is "+ array1[i]);

            }
            a=0;
        }
        else
        {
            array1[i]=s1;
            a=(i+2);
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: because size of the array is 1 and you are adding two elements. see a=1 in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `array` is of size 1 (a is 1 at the beginning of your code).
The first input works because i is 0 and `array1[0]` exists. The second input crashes because `array1[1]` does not exist.

You need to increase your array. That can be done by copying the array into a larger one and using the result of the copy, but that is clumsy.

Better way to do it is to use an `ArrayList` instead of a simple `array` and you do not have to worry about the size as it is managed automatically.

Comment: But i am incrementing the value of a in the else section.Why is the value not increasing.

Comment: You are incrementing the `a` but not your array. There are 2 different things. Your array is like a bottle of 1 liter. A is one at the beginning and all is fine, a means it will fit 1 liter in your bottle. Later on you say a is 2 - it will fit 2 litters in your botthe - but you keep the same bottle.

Answer (score 0):

For one, a is only incremented when they press q, when you go to the else statement. So the the for loop is going to end after a couple of iterations.

You also set a to 0 in the inside for loop, making sure it won't run more.

Also, your quit code doesn't quit.